# relativistic temperatures energy assumptions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, relativity

why is the assumption   $k_bT>>mc^2$ made for relativistic temperatures, where did the kT come from and how is it related to mc^2?

Answer (score 2):

$kT$ is related to the kinetic translation energy by the [equipartition theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem). You are saying that the mean kinetic energy, is much greater than the rest energy. The particle has a large or relativistic velocity.

The limit $kT>> mc^2$ is called ultrarelativistic limit. It means you can approximate the energy momentum relation $E^2=(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2$ by $E\approx pc$.

Comment: thanks, so does that just mean we have to use the relativistic K.E,  E-mc^2 and not the (1/2)mv^2?

Comment: Please consider to check out the edit in the answer.

Comment: what about when its not ultrarelativistic, but just relativistic? for example 0.5 times speed of light